# How to use dp to calculate shadows - web development HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design, dpi

I have question about using dp in web development. Im currently reading [google material design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows) and they are talking about elevation and shadows based on dp. How can I use this in web development? Is there any way to calculate this how to create shadow based on dp with HTML CSS?

Example from the web page:

Raised button

Resting state: 2dp

Pressed state: 8dp

For desktop only, raised buttons can have an elevation of:

Resting state: 0dp

Pressed state: 2dp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Google Material design documents](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-density-independent-pixels-dp-):

> A dp is equal to one physical pixel on a screen with a density of 160.
>   To calculate dp:
>
> **dp = (width in pixels * 160) /  screen density**
>
> When writing CSS, use px wherever dp or sp is stated. Dp only needs to
>   be used in developing for Android.

and *screen density* is

> Screen resolution refers to the total number pixels in a display.
>
> **screen density = screen width (or height) in pixels / screen width (or
>   height) in inches**

So it depends on the screen width and height. There are some converters on the web to calculate for each density. But as most screens are still 72dpi (not mentioned the HDPI screens), I think that is a proper starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There are no CSS units that are truly device-independent. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths. In particular, the absolute units might not match their physical measurements.

If physical units were true to their purpose, you could use something like points; points are close enough to dps:

```
1 in = 72 pt
1 in = 160 dp
=> 1 dp = 72 / 160 pt
```

If you use SCSS, you can write a function to return in pts:

```
@function dp($_dp) {
  @return (72 / 160) * $_dp + pt;
}
```

And use it:

```
.shadow-2 {
  height: dp(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Material's shadows they only really use the *concept* of dp to attempt to relay how elements should be layered.

i.e.

```
2dp < 8dp // 2 is layered under 8
// or
2dp (resting) => 8dp (focused)
```

What they are referring to is **z-depth** (or on the z-axis). This cannot be converted straight to CSS. *When they talk about elevation levels they are not referring to x & y or width & height dimension.*
[See design guide page on elevation.](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows)

If you are simply looking for the values for CSS shadows check here.
https://github.com/mrmlnc/material-shadows/blob/master/material-shadows.scss

That is as close to converting z-depth dp to CSS values. The CSS values *do* match Google's Polymer elements though so it's most likely spot on.

Good Luck!